# How to rename "struct first_name" to "struct second_name"

Tags: c++, c, struct

I have a structure called `struct first_name` and some helper functions. They are used in various modules. And in some modules, the struct name does not self-describes so I want to change it name.

It will not be hardship to change the name to `second_name`. But my company's coding convention requires to change it to `struct second_name` (still keeping keyword `struct`).

Currently I do:

`#define second_name first_name`

so that whenever I declare

`struct second_name a`

the preprocessing will translate them back to `struct first_name` and I can utilizes the helper functions.

Except above solution, is there any official way to do this?

For example: 
Here is the structure for an entry of a double-linked list

```
struct list_head {
    struct list_head *next, *prev;
};
```

Now I want to create a hash list and each entry is:

```
struct hash_list_head {
    struct hash_list_head *next, *prev;
};
```

The hash_list_head and list_head are similar--> how to rename "struct list_head" to "struct hash_list_head"

Comment: `:%s/first_name/second_name/g` - I must be missing something.

Comment: Is it in just one file or spread across multiple files ?

Comment: @WhozCraig it doesn't seem to be about renaming in code.

Comment: Why change it at all? What's the benefit? Against the considerable cost and risk?

Comment: @WhozCraig: NO, it is not about code refactoring.

Comment: @vad So what is it about exactly?

Comment: Edit all the files where "struct first_name" is used and change it to "struct second_name". Where's the problem? If it's used in more than a thousand files you might want to write a script instead of doing it manually. Then read the diff to make sure the changes you or the script did are correct. Where's the problem?

Comment: @Art One of the problems can be that if you're in a large enough team you can never checkout all the required files at the same time.

Comment: @EJP What ancient source management tool would behave like that? I haven't heard of this kind of problems since 1999 when I was forced to use ClearCase and even then it was solvable with branches.

Comment: @EJP: I added an example

Comment: Your example is pointless. A 'hash list' is still a list, whatever else it may be. Why do you want to use two names for the same thing? Maybe what you're really looking for is templates.

Comment: @Art *Any* 'ancient source management tool'. That's the point. It can happen. I didn't say it was compulsory, or universal.

Comment: How about

`#define _A { int a; char b; ... }`

and then

`struct A _A;`

and

`struct B _A;`

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must refer to the type as both `struct first_name` AND `struct second_name`, then

```
#define second_name first_name
```

is the way to go, as I don't remember any other way to achieve this in in pure C. As for C++ go for the @EJP solution.

Comment: Not my vote, but you need to give a reason why this is 'the way to go'.

Answer (score 3):

As you are writing C++ you could use inheritance:

```
struct second_name : public first_name {};
```

But frankly I cannot see the point. You don't need two names for he same type. You need different names for the *instances.*

Comment: +1 or typedef  if your lazy like I am.

Comment: @WhozCraig He specifically ruled that out.

Comment: certainly; by policy, not practicality. I agree with your comment in the general-list below the question, now more than ever.

Comment: A constraint is a constraint.